# Is it possible to run a fold operation on the GPU in a browser using WebGL?

Tags: javascript, browser, webgl, gpu

I am running a data processing application that is pretty much:

```
var f = function(a,b){ /* any function of type int -> int -> int */ };
var g = function(a){ /* any function of type int -> int */ };
function my_computation(state){
    var data = state[2];
    for (var i=0,l=data.length,res=0; i<l; ++i)
        res = f(res,g(data[i]));
    state[3] = res;
    return res;
}
```

This pattern is pretty much that of a `foldl`. That computation is not fast enough on CPU. Is it possible to somehow run that computation on the GPU, on the browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your comment:

> I don't know much about vertex shaders but to my knowledge it worked in isolated pixels, and for the folding you'd kinda need an accumulation pattern. No?

If you want to use WebGL for computation over an array, you most likely will want to do it in a fragment shader, not a vertex shader. If you use input geometry that covers the entire viewport, a fragment shader is then simply a program that computes an image pixel-by-pixel. It can use as inputs numeric parameters and arbitrary *textures*. Furthermore, you can render output to a texture.

This is how you do inputs: you stash the input data in a texture, and have the fragment shader do lookups in the texture. It's perfectly normal to do multiple offset lookups in a texture; for example, this is how a blur effect works.

You're right to be concerned about accumulation. There is no native way to do a fold over all pixels. However, if you can express your algorithm in a "map-reduce" fashion, where the reduce operation combines two outputs and doesn't care about whether they are the input from a previous reduce step, then you can do it like so:

1. Load your input data into a 1-pixel high by N-pixel wide texture. (Not sure whether using square textures might give better upper limits, but this is simpler to describe.)
2. Run your "map" (`g`, non-accumulating computation) shader program producing an intermediate-outputs texture.
3. Run a shader which performs the "reduce" operation (`f`) on each *pair of adjacent pixels* (or similar) of the intermediate texture, producing another texture half as wide.
4. Do the same thing again on that output.

This will get you your single answer in only O(log n) JavaScript operations.

Comment: That is exactly what I want. I'm glad to know it is possible. I wish I had an example to work with, though. Tutorials for WebGL are rare and for what I want it is nonexistent. Simple things like "how do I create a texture", "how do I run a shader on it", "how do I store the result on the GPU and run yet another shader on it", "how do I finally get the result on the host machine", etc etc will be really hard to find. But there I go...

Comment: @Viclib Did you figure out how to proceed? I'm looking for exactly the same thing.

Comment: @erb I've managed to get a reduction by using webgl to render from a 1024x1024 texture to a 512x512 texture, to a 256x256 texture and so on. Each rendering step computed 4 numbers together. I couldn't obtain any speedup with that, however it was fast enough to suspect a more skilled glsl programmer could do it. I've found a JS library that does it for you, but I wasn't interested on the problem anymore when I did. It is good and I think you should find it, but I don't remember any keywords so you'll have to ask around if anyone knows a lib that does what webcl would do, except with webgl.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes. I've often though about this myself. Your data would be attached as a vertex attribute buffer and a custom shader would execute you fold code, 'rendering' the results to an off-screen buffer. You would then read the result buffer back into CPU memory.

Comment: Motivational, but if I'm not asking much, could you elaborate a little bit? The part I don't get is how the shader would execute such fold code. I don't know much about vertex shaders but to my knowledge it worked in isolated pixels, and for the folding you'd kinda need an accumulation pattern. No? (Well maybe not if you go for a "Google's Mapreduce" style, in parallel, but you'd still need a way to work with 2 different pixels at the same time, for example, summing them...)

Answer (score 1):

Given that you want to run it on the browser, you are limited by what WebGL/extensions support, specifically on CPU access to GPU data.

You can take a look at shader code for filters/edge detect in below code-base that show how you can do this in a `fragment shader`.

https://github.com/prabindh/sgxperf/blob/master/sgxperf_strings.cpp

After this, you can access the data using `readPixels`. NOTE - the fragment shader can only output fixed-point data.